# Fancybox with owl carousel misses CSS

Tags: javascript, jquery, fancybox, owl-carousel, fancybox-3

I'm building a fancybox modal(v3) with inside it two owl carousels(v2). It's used as a product quick view function.

The problem I'm facing is that the second carousel (used for the thumbs) doesn't have core css styles applied, while the carousel is actually initialized.

So the two carousels are initialized but one just won't use styling from the actual owl-carousel.css stylesheet.

I'm completly confused.

I've created a [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/meules/fqd2c90e/22/) here with the actual problem.

My html

```
<div id="quick-shop-modal" class="cd-quick-view" style="display:none;">
  <div class="product-images-slider">
    <div class="slider-container"></div>
    <div class="thumbnail-slider-container"></div>
  </div>
</div>


<a href="javascript:;" class="quick_view item-add-btn" title="Quick view">Quick shop</a>
```

Jquery

```
$(document).ready(function() {
  $(".quick_view").on('click', function() {
    var url = 'some-url'
    $.fancybox.open({
      touch: false,
      src: '#quick-shop-modal',
      type: 'inline',
      beforeShow: function() {
        quick_shop(url)
      }
    });
  });  
});

function quick_shop(url) {
  var $modal = $('#quick-shop-modal');

  $.getJSON(url, function(data) {
    $modal.data('product', data.product);
    var product = data.product;
    var images = '';
    $.each(product.images, function(index, image_id) {
      images += '<div class="item"><div class="content"><img src="https://via.placeholder.com/350x150" class="img-responsive"></div></div>';
    });

    $modal.find('.slider-container').html('<div id="slider" class="slider owl-carousel">' + images + '</div>')
    $modal.find('.thumbnail-slider-container').html('<div id="thumbnailSlider" class="thumbnail-slider">' + images + '</div>')
    $modal.find('.slider').owlCarousel({
      loop: false,
      nav: false,
      items: 1
    }).on('changed.owl.carousel', function(e) {
      $modal.find('.thumbnail-slider').trigger('to.owl.carousel', [e.item.index, 300, true]);
    });
    $modal.find('.thumbnail-slider').owlCarousel({
      loop: false,
      margin: 10,
      nav: false,
      items: 3,
      stagePadding: 40
    }).on('click', '.owl-item', function() {
      $modal.find('.slider').trigger('to.owl.carousel', [$(this).index(), 300, true]);
    }).on('changed.owl.carousel', function(e) {
      $modal.find('.slider').trigger('to.owl.carousel', [e.item.index, 300, true]);
    });

  });
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

1) I do not think that anyone would be able to help you without seeing live demo and probably no-one will spend time to create it for you.

2) From you code, it seems that changing one slider would trigger `change` callback on both sliders. IF that is true, than that could cause the issues.

3) It is not possible to tell what role of fancybox is here just by looking at those pieces of code (e.g., what is `webdinge_quick_shop` doing; if `#webdinge-quick-shop-modal` exists, then fancybox should work fine)

Edit & Answer to updated question -

Your 2nd own carousel is missing `owl-carousel` classname, simply add `.owl-carousel` to `.thumbnail-slider` element, see http://jsfiddle.net/zLfnmrx1/

Comment: I've completely updated my question inclusing a fiddle. Thanks for pointing that out :)

Comment: I have updated the answer. btw, is there a particular reason why are you using owl slider instead of displaying images natively with fancybox? Are you missing some features? If you wish, you can easily redesign, for example - https://codepen.io/anon/pen/RYNzbw

Comment: I can't be that stupid :( My god.... :) The reason I use owl is because I can't get native fancybox images to work with in my quickshop function. Easy as that. And I already created a function to use owl on multiple pages. So I thought let's use it in my quickshop module as well. I just don't understand how that works with dynamic added images in fancybox and with two sliders that sync to position. You may help with that offcourse haha ;)